# Can't import flask-marshmallow into python3 project

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, marshmallow

I have **only** python 3.8.5 installed.

I started diving into Python and Flask for the first time (I'm coming from the javascript side of things).  I've already ran into an interesting issue in just my first few lines of code.

I was able to run `pipenv install flask flask-sqlalchemy flask-marshmallow marshmallow-sqlalchemy` and they all seemed to have installed just fine. They all appear in the pipfile.lock. flask-marshmallow is version 0.13.0.

[pipfile.lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOC6d.png)

When I started coding, I was able to import flask and flask_sqlalchemy with no issues. Intellisense even helped me out with them. But `from flask-marshmallow import Marshmallow` didn't seem to work.

When I ran `python app.py` I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_marshmallow'
```

I've tried uninstalling flask-marshmallow and marshmallow and reinstalling. The console always says the installation is successful but I can't seem to import it when all the other packages seem to work fine.

What a great start to a new language xD Here is the whole file so far for reference, if I remove the marshmallow line it starts without any issues

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that, because you have created a `pipenv`, you have set the Python interpreter path correctly in your IDE.

I was facing the exact issue (and that is how I reached this question). I am using VS code, was using `python3.8` and `pipenv`.

Even though I have installed the packages using `pip3`, I was facing import issues while running the code. After a futile search on the Internet, I realised that the issue was very silly.

The Python interpreter path (`Cntrl+Shift+P` -> `Select Interpreter`) was not set to the newly created `pipenv`. After I have set the interpreter path properly, the code resumed to function as expected.

Comment: Confirmed this solved my issue. On MacOS VS Code, you'd need to CMD+Shift+P to select the python interpreter and select the pipenv one.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to check the site packages file and make sure that it is installed in it if not then it is installed in other directory
Also try working it in another normal python file and check if that works too
Check syntax also i know i know its obvious but just saying

Comment: plus check if its compatible with the python version cause there are lots of packages not compatible with version 3.8.x

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to run the command `flask db init`, and it would give the error above. I got it to work by running the command with sudo privileges `sudo flask db init`. I hope this can help someone else out in a similar situation!